# Get baseurl in javascript file-codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I need   to get the base url of the project in a javascript  function.
my code is

```
function add_more()
{
    var numrows=parseInt(document.frm_add_announcement.cnnumrows.value)+1;
    var strinner="";
    var ni = document.getElementById('content');
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    var divIdName = 'my'+numrows+'Div1';
    newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
    document.frm_add_announcement.cnnumrows.value=numrows;
    //alert("asdAS");

      strinner="<div class='row'> <div class='col-md-3'><div class='form-group'><input type='text' id='imgcaption"+numrows+"' name='imgcaption"+numrows+"' placeholder='Attachment caption'  class='form-control'/></div> </div><div class='col-md-2'><div class='form-group'><input type='file' id='document"+numrows+"' name='document"+numrows+"' onclick='disableurl("+numrows+")' /></div></div><div class='col-md-1'><label for=''></label><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='../../../images/close3.png' title='Click to remove File'  id='clear_multiple"+numrows+"' height='25px'  style='cursor:pointer' onclick='remove("+numrows+")'/></div><div class='col-md-3'><div class='form-group'><input type='text'  id='url"+numrows+"' name='url"+numrows+"' placeholder='Attachment URL' onkeyup='disablefile("+numrows+")'   class='form-control'/></div></div><div class='col-md-3'><div class='form-group'><select class='form-control' id='target_type"+numrows+"' name='target_type"+numrows+"'  ><option>-Choose-</option><option>Same tab</option><option>New tab</option></select></div></div></div>";

 //$(".remove-btn").live('click',function() {
                //$(this).parent().remove();
            //});

    newdiv.innerHTML=strinner;
    ni.appendChild(newdiv);

}
```

need to get the `baseurl` in the `src=""` of the image in `strinner`.

Comment: use <?php echo baseurl();?>if it is already defined in config file.

Comment: If your js code is in php file you can use `var path=<?php echo base_url('') ?>`. If its a js file then you need to add the above line in php while were the js file included. Now the js file can access the  js variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using external js file then You can create hidden field in view with value as

```
<input type="hidden" id="base" value="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">
```

Then access it in js using id like

```
var base_url = $('#base').val();
```

Comment: Although this is working, this should not be marked as an answer. It's a very ugly workaround.

Answer (score 3):

You can initiate a JavaScript variable in your PHP file and then access the variable in any JavaScript file.

```
<script>
    var base_url = "<?= base_url('') ?>";
</script>
```

You have to load other JavaScript files and script tags after the above script to ensure the *base_url* variable is defined before it is referenced.

Comment: but when iam entering the baseurl in src="" the url gets concatenated with the current url when page is loaded

Comment: have you setting your config.php file for _'base_url'_ to your default URL?@VimalS

Comment: do you put the last slash in your config.php file? can you show the _'base_url'_ in your config file? @VimalS

Answer (score 2):

In codeigniter no more headache on getting the base_url.Just Load `url` helper in controller as below.OR you can load it on `application/config/autoload.php`

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Then inside script of your php file...

```
<script>
var base_url = <?php echo base_url(); ?>
alert(base_url);
</script>
```

Set `base_url` inside `application/config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://domain_name/';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the current url quite easily in JavaScript with window.location

You have access to the segments of that URL via this locations object. For

Example:

```
var base_url = window.location.origin;
// "http://stackoverflow.com"

var host = window.location.host;
// stackoverflow.com

var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
```